# How to configure "-nlt MULTILINESTRING" for DXF export?

Tags: qgis, dxf

When I try and export a polygon shapefile to DXF, the resulting features in AutoCAD are hatch patterns, which is as expected if you read http://www.gdal.org/drv_dxf.html, "Polygon and MultiPolygon features are written as HATCH entities".

After doing some more digging I found that OGR2OGR can export a polygon shapefile to polylines using the following:

```
"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\ogr2ogr.exe" -f "DXF" some.dxf some_shapefile.shp -nlt MULTILINESTRING
```

Can I somehow add "-nlt MULTILINESTRING" to the Custom Options boxes using the "Save As" function in Qgis?